# Not Serializable: com/salesforce/api/fast/List$$lcom/salesforce/api/Messaging/SingleEmailMessage$$r

Tags: apex, visualforce, singleemailmessage

There was a similar question asked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112984/not-serializable-com-salesforce-api-fast-listlcom-salesforce-api-messaging-se), but it wasn't really answered.

I've got a function that sends an e-mail for the User from a Visualforce Page, pretty simple:

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:pageMessages id="emailresponse" />
<apex:form >
  <div class="form-group">
    <apex:outputLabel for="to" value="To:" />
    <apex:inputText id="to" styleClass="form-control" value="{!to}" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <apex:outputLabel for="subject" value="Subject:" />
    <apex:inputText id="subject" styleClass="form-control" value="{!subject}" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <apex:outputLabel for="message" value="Message:" />
    <apex:inputTextarea id="message" styleClass="form-control" value="{!message}" />
  </div>
  <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-default" value="Send" action="{!sendEmail}" reRender="emailresponse" />
</apex:form>
```

This just takes in 3 parameters: `to`, `subject` and `message` and calls the function `sendEmail` in the Controller.

With all of the variable assignments, this is what the Controller looks like:

**Controller:**

```
private List<String> toList {
  get;
  set;
}

public String to {
  get;
  set;
}

private void createToList(String to) {
  toList = new List<String>();

  this.toList = to.split('\\;');
}

public String subject {
  get;
  set;
}

public String message {
  get;
  set;
}

public List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messageList {
  get;
  set;
}

public PageReference sendEmail() {
  User usr = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Name, Title, Email, Phone FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

  createToList(to);

  messageList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
  messageList = EmailHelper.createPersonalMessage(toList, subject, message, usr, false);

  try {
    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] r = Messaging.sendEmail(messageList);

    if (r.get(0).isSuccess()) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, messageList.size() + ' messages sent.'));
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'There was a problem sending your messages.'));
    System.debug('@@@@@ Error: ' + e);
  }

  return null;
}
```

As you can see this is pretty simple, it's just assigning the variables (albeit splitting e-mail addresses if they're comma-seperated), calling a function in `EmailHelper` called `CreateMessage` to create a list of single e-mail messages and trying to send it!

Finally, the Helper class which puts it all together:

**Helper Class**

```
public static List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> createPersonalMessage(List<String> toList, String subjectString, String messageString, User fromUser, Boolean doRemoveUnsubscribed) {
  List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messageList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>(); // Create the new message list

  String footer = buildFooter(fromUser); // Build the footer

  Map<String, Id> mapEmailToContactId = new Map<String, Id>(); // Create a new map for the TargetObjectId

  for (Contact c : [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email IN :toList]) { // Loop through the list, mapping the e-mail address to the contact
    mapEmailToContactId.put(c.Email, c.Id); // Add them
  }

  for (String to : toList) { // Loop through the Call List
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); // Create a new message

    message.setToAddresses(new List<String>{
      to
    }); // Set the to address...
    message.setSubject(subjectString); // ... Add the subject...
    message.setHtmlBody(messageString + footer); // ... The body plus the footer we built earlier...

    if (mapEmailToContactId.containsKey(to)) {
      message.setTargetObjectId(mapEmailToContactId.get(to)); // ... The target object (if it exists)...
    }

    messageList.add(message); // ... Add it!
  }

  messageList = removeDuplicates(messageList); // Remove duplicates

  if (doRemoveUnsubscribed) { // Do we remove Unsubscribed people?
    messageList = removeUnsubscribed(messageList); // If so, remove them
  }

  return messageList; // Send the kust back
}

public static String buildFooter(User fromUser) {
  return '<br><br><b><span style="color:#767171; font-family:arial,sans-serif">' + fromUser.FirstName + ' ' + fromUser.LastName + '</span>'; // This gets ridiculously long, but it's creating a footer for the e-mails
}
```

As mentioned in the title, I'm getting this error:

> Not Serializable: com/salesforce/api/fast/List$$lcom/salesforce/api/Messaging/SingleEmailMessage$$r

I've tried Exchanging `Messaging.SendEmailResult[] r = Messaging.sendEmail(messageList);` for just `Messaging.sendEmail(messageList);` but still get the crash, sending e-mails with and without multiple address, comma-seperated. They work whether I enter 1 or a dozen thinking it maybe something to do with one of those two things.

I'm assuming `$$r` is somehow in reference to the Controller line: `Messaging.SendEmailResult[] r`, what's odd is that the e-mails **do actually send**.

So, what is causing this error and what does the error actually mean?

Comment: At what point in the control flow do you get the error?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I'm not sure. I'm getting the e-mail, so I can assume `Messaging.SendEmailResult[] r = Messaging.sendEmail(messageList);` is working and that the helper class is doing it's business at least. I'll add some debugging in to see if I can trace the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only reason Salesforce is trying to serialize the `List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>` property is because you are adding it to the `View State`. You don't need to, however, as you do not reference it in your markup. Simply **remove** the `messageList` property and scope it locally. If you really want to keep it as a property, mark it as `transient`.

### Repro

The MVR is simple here:

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="Demo">
    <apex:form />
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class Demo
{
    public List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages { get; private set; }
    public Demo()
    {
        messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>
        {
            new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage()
        };
    }
}
```

### Fix

Marking `messages` as `transient` resolves the error, as does removing it as a property and scoping it locally to the method where it is used.

**Transient**

```
public with sharing class Demo
{
    public transient List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages { get; private set; }
    public Demo()
    {
        messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>
        {
            new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage()
        };
    }
}
```

**Locally scoped**

```
public with sharing class Demo
{
    public Demo()
    {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>
        {
            new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage()
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, worked like a charm as answers normally do from yourself! I really need to look into `transient` and `viewstates` as I'm woefully under-informed on them.

Comment: Incidentally, I hadn't realised until you said I wasn't referencing `public List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messageList`, so marked it as private also. Without knowing more about this, I'm not sure if this helps with this particular problem, but if nothing else it'll make a bit more "secure".

Comment: You don't really need to add it as a controller property at all, though. You don't seem to reference it *anywhere* outside your `sendEmail` method.

Comment: You're right actually, I'm not. Thanks for that. I'm not entirely sure why I made it a controller property to begin with!

Comment: N.B. this error can also occur if the non-transient property references objects in other classes that in turn reference the `Messaging` class. A recent example for me was referencing a variable of type `fflib_ISobjectUnitOfWork` from the Trailhead UnitOfWork pattern that in turn has deep within its concrete class a reference to the `Message` class.